# error: exec plugin: invalid apiVersion "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm laptop OS is Ubuntu Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and AWS EKS is 1.27

when I execute -> `kubectl version`, I get:

> error: exec plugin: invalid apiVersion "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1"

When I install the snap 1.23.17 it works, but anything above this version does not work and throws above error.

and also when it comes to helm. helm install does not work and throws the following error too. helm version is latest and I have tried with Version:"v3.10.3" and I get the same error.

> Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: exec plugin: invalid apiVersion "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1"

I tried different version and nothing works. I'm expecting to get helm install working and why kubeclt client is not working if I install anything above 1.23 version in my ubuntu laptop.

Comment: You can hit this if you generated your Kubernetes configuration using an older version of the AWS CLI.  Make sure you have a current version of the tool and re-run `aws eks update-kubeconfig`.  (Not particularly programming-related, though.)

Answer (score 0):

this is

```
cat ~/.kube/config
```

Check the current-context value

```
rm ~/.kube/config
```

if you are running EKSCTL execute the below command

```
aws eks update-kubeconfig --name <cluster_name> --region <region>
```